# apache ignite memory estimation

Tags: memory, ignite, estimation

I have 100million records, one record is about 80 bytes, as the ignite mentioned capacity planning, these records will occupy 10G memory, but actually in ignite with persistence enabled, the ssd disk is used about 40G, and the assigned dataregionconfiguration maxsize 20G is all used, no free left(use 'free -g' command to check), why?

Comment: I'm dizzy just from reading your post. Can you please accompany every memory number with a config snipped or command+output that features this number?

Comment: suppose I have 1 million records to add into ignite, each record has 100 bytes, how many off-heap memory will be used with/without persistence enabled

Comment: Try it and see! That's your best shot here.